# Script for compressing new folders in the parent folder

Tags: scripts, cron

I'm using `Backup-Utils` application for the backup of our GitHub Enterprise.
This application run every night and create the following structure in the backup directory.

```
/backup/
   20191201T000001/
   20191202T000001/
   20191203T000001/
   etc...
```

What I would like to perform, if this is possible, is to run a `cron` script that will compress only the new folder created by the `Backup-Utils`.

example:

Day 1: I ran a script to compress the first folder (`/backup/20191201T000001/`) what I want is to increment the script to compress the new folder (`/backup/20191202T000001/`) in Day 2 and so on.

Comment: Does `/backup/20191201T000001/` folder could be removed after compressing, or it must stay here? Also, you can use the date as increment, because your folder is named based on it as `yyyymmddT000001`

Comment: I would like to keep at least 5 backups days for quick restore. Could you provide the script base on date for increment?

Comment: So you could add a cron job to clean backup that are older than 5 days

Comment: `0 5 * * * find /backup/ -mindepth +1 -mtime +5 -delete` would do the job for clearing backup older than 5 days; it would execute the command each day at 5:00 AM

Comment: Thanks for the delete command. But what is the script command to compress the latest dir that was created without backing up the previous one.

Comment: Most backup tools already compress the saved data. In that case an additional compression is not useful. Check if this is the case with your backup tool.

Comment: @M.D does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation to use commands of the answer (at the end of the answer) :

We would use the `date` command, because each backup is named as YYYYMMDDT000001 :

```
date '+%Y%m%d'
```

To define which backup must be compressed, we use the `find` command, and we use the `-exec` option to compress it at same time :

```
find /backup -iname $(date '+%Y%m%d')T000001 -exec zip -r $(date '+%Y%m%d')T000001.zip $(date '+%Y%m%d')T000001 {} \;
```

Further explanation of the command :

- `/backup` is your backup folder
- `-iname` ask `find` command to search each directory/file which is named as said by his parameter (here, it's the result of the command `date '+%Y%m%d'`)
- `-exec` would execute the command with `find` output
- `zip -r` would created a compressed file which would be named with result of `date '+%Y%m%d'` and with `.zip` extension after (you can define an absolute/relative path, in order to have a folder for compressed backup and backup separate), and the file which would be compress has the name defined by `date '+%Y%m%d'` command

For example, the command would be generate like that :

```
find /backup -iname 20191206T000001 -exec zip -r ../compress_backup/20191206T000001.zip 20191206T000001 {} \;
```

`date '+%Y%m%d'` would return `20191206`, so `find` search for `20191206T000001` file, and compress it in `../compress_backup` folder (which is next to `/backup`) with the name `20191206T000001.zip`

---

Commands for answer :

Now, we can create the cron job, which would run 1 time per day (and as said by [OP in comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194051/script-for-compressing-new-folders-in-the-parent-folder/1194216?noredirect=1#comment2002214_1194216), `%` character as got a special meaning inside cron command - forcing newlines, which we don't want to - so we had `\\` character each time to force cronjob to use the command literally like that):

```
0 4 * * * find /backup -iname $(date '+\%Y\%m\%d')T000001 -exec zip -r $(date '+\%Y\%m\%d')T000001.zip $(date '+\%Y\%m\%d')T000001 {} \;
```

This would execute this command each day at 4:00 AM, and as mentionned in [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194051/script-for-compressing-new-folders-in-the-parent-folder/1194216#comment1999286_1194051), we can removed backup that are older than 5 days with this command :

```
0 5 * * * find /backup/ -mindepth +1 -mtime +5 -delete
```

This command would remove each file inside `/backup` folder that are older than 5 days, and would be executed each day at 5:00 AM

Comment: Yes your answer really help. Thanks for your Help..

Comment: Don't forget to tick it as *Accepted* if it solved your issue, or add an edit : comment what's wrong if not

Comment: The % sign has a special meaning in crontab. it's changed to newline and any string after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input. To force cron to interpret it literally, you have to escape it:   0 4 * * * find /backup -iname $(date '+\%Y\%m\%d')T000001 -exec zip -r $(date '+\%Y\%m\%d')T000001.zip $(date '+\%Y\%m\%d')T000001 {} \;

Comment: @M.D I add your comment in the answer